# have an array with colors that I want to rotate infinitely through setInterval

Tags: javascript, setinterval, infinite

So I have an simple array that contains few colors and a function that adds those colors to the backgroundColor property to the body. I am using setInterval to run through the colors, but as it has gone through the array it stops. I would like it to just keep going, either to begin from the start or it could also go in reverse order. How would I do this?

```
let colors = ['crimson','dodgerblue','gold', 'deeppink'];
const body = document.body;
let index = 0;

function change() {
body.style.backgroundColor = colors[index++];
}

var timer = setInterval(change, 4000);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need a little bit of extra logic to check the `index` and reset it to 0 if it's gone beyond the end of the array.

The simplest way is to use the `%` "modulus" operator:

```
function change() {
  index = (index + 1) % colors.length;
  body.style.backgroundColor = colors[index];
}
```

Comment: Ah, thanks! Yeah, I assumed it was related to the modulus. Never did grasp it fully and how it works.

Answer (score 0):

You have to ensure the index reach the end of the array and if so, reset it.
Something like:

```
function change() {
  index = index === colors.length - 1 ? 0 : index++;
  body.style.backgroundColor = colors[index];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let colors = ['green','dodgerblue','gold', 'deeppink'];
const body = document.body;
let index = 0;

function change() {
console.log('going')
body.style.backgroundColor = colors[index++];
if(index == colors.length) {
    index = 0;
  }
}

var timer = setInterval(change, 1000);
```

I simply added some logic that if index reached the end of the array, reset it back to zero